# How to get size of different kinds of types in the same function using C?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a function which increases the size of a dynamic memory object created with malloc. The function should as arguments take a pointer to the memory block to be increased, the current size of the block and the amount the block is going to be increased.

Something like this:

```
int getMoreSpace(void **pnt, int size, int add) {
    xxxxxx *tmp; /* a pointer to the same as pnt */
    if (tmp = realloc(pnt, (size+add)*sizeof(xxxxxx))) { /* get size of what pnt points to */
        *pnt=tmp;
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I want the function to work no matter what pnt points to. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of function cannot possibly work, because `pnt` is local and the new pointer is lost as soon as the function returns. You could take an argument of type `xxxxxx **` so that you could update the pointer, but then you're stuck with only supporting a single type.

The real problem is that you're writing an unnecessary and harmful wrapper for `realloc`. Simply use `realloc` directly as it was meant to be used. There is no way to make it simpler or more efficient by wrapping it; it's already as simple as possible.

Comment: I don't really get what you're saying. Why does it matter that pnt is local? I only need it till the function returns.

Also why is this wrapper harmful? I'm doing this kind of size increment several times in my program under different circumstances as far as I can see this function only makes my coder cleaner and simpler because it eliminates typing in the same thing lots of times (isn't that the point of functions anyway?).

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think that there is no such thing as a 'local' pointer in C.

Comment: @Stefanos: function arguments are "local variables" in the sense that they go out of scope when the function returns. Assigning a new value to `ptr` will not have any effect; in fact the compiler can and should optimize out the assignment.

Comment: @paldepind: After `getMoreSpace` returns, the address of the new block of memory is lost. This is a memory leak. Also note that even if this worked, the caller would have to check for success or failure, but this is just as much code as using `realloc` directly.

Comment: @R.. the function argument indeed has a local scope, but the variable is a pointer, which means it can point at the original variable. Run this:
int func(int *arg){
 *arg = 10;
}
int main(){
 int testArg = 5;
 func(&testArg);
 printf("testArg=%d\n", testArg);
}

Comment: @Stefanos Kalantzis: but then you're dereferencing the pointer and changing the value, not the address itself.

Comment: @A: I see. You are right that my current implementation of the function is buggy because it only changes the local copy of the variable. I've updated the post to something that I think could work.
Also you are right that the caller still will have to check for succes. But this still saves me having to through the hassle of creating a temporary value and having to test against it every time I need to increase the size of an array.

Comment: @R.. realloc does not change the original pointer. thus the name.. REalloc. it extends the allocated memory to that pointer.

Comment: The new version is broken unless the caller actually has a `void *` variable and passes the address of it. Passing a pointer to a `char *` or `struct mystruct *` variable when a pointer to `void *` is required has *undefined behavior*. Doing something like `void *tmp = myptr; getMoreSpace(&tmp, ...); myptr = tmp;` defeats the purpose of the simplification you're trying to achieve. **Simply don't do it.** Calling `realloc` directly and checking for error the standard way is **simply the simplest you can make it**. All that's left is the fundamental complexity.

Comment: @Stefanos: You are completely wrong. After a successful `realloc`, the new address of the object may or may not be the same as the original address passed, and if they differ, the original address may no longer be used for anything. Why are you commenting on an issue you obviously know nothing about?

Comment: @R.. You are right I forgot that bit. That does not change the fact that I provided a mechanism for his question. See my answer now.

Comment: Ok. So the new version is broken and the old was broken too. Then how do I actually change the pointer that the function receives as first argument?

Comment: @paldepind: You don't. There's no way to do what you want with functions in the C language. You could probably use macros, but the usual issues apply. @Stefanos: Your answer is not C.

Comment: @R.. please explain. I am always trying to learn more.. Why it's not C ?

Comment: C does not let you define a function inside the body of another function.

Comment: Then why it compiles and runs with gcc ?

Comment: gcc lets you do a lot of things that aren't C. If you want to make sure your code is legitimate C, you should use `-std=c99` and perhaps also `-pedantic`.

Comment: For this particular case (nested functions), `-pedantic` *is* required to see a warning.

Answer (score 2):

You pass in the size as an argument.  You can use a convenience macro to make it look the same as your function:

```
#define getMoreSpace(P, SZ, ADD) getMoreSpaceFunc(&(P), sizeof(*(P)), (SZ), (ADD))

int getMoreSpace(void **pnt, size_t elem_size, int size, int add) {
    *pnt = ...
}
```

Edit to show that your convenience macro would also need to add call-by-reference semantics.

Comment: Why do you use a macro? Does sizeof work just by passing it a variable? I though it only accepted a type as argument?

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator.  It must be able to see the type.  The macro substitutes as text in the original code where the type of the variable is visible.  Inside your function you still lose type information but the macro passed in the size for you.  Further you can use the macro (as I illustrated in the edit) to take the address of the target pointer for you.

Comment: ...also, I voted up R's answer because I don't think you *should* do this, but I thought a technical answer to your question would be enlightening as well.

Comment: But will this function accept anything anything besides a pointer to a pointer to void as the first argument?

Comment: The *function* won't but the macro will.  Actually "pointer to pointer to void" is its own can of worms which you can learn about in other stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Ok. To be honest I don't really understand how this macro works. But it works that I can see. I'll vote up your answer and I appreciate it because it was the best that really answered the question I asked. R however, did convince me that I really shouldn't do this so I'll accept his answer.

Comment: Note your version has a bug unless the argument to `P` has type `void *`. Conversion from `foo **` to `void **` is undefined in C.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Pass in the element size as a separate parameter:</strike>

```
int getMoreSpace(void **pnt, int size, int add, size_t eltSize) 
{     
  void *tmp;
  if (tmp = realloc(pnt, (size+add)*eltSize)) 
  { 
    *pnt=tmp;
    return 1;
  }
  else 
    return 0; 
} 
...

int *p = malloc(100 * sizeof *p);
...
if (!getMoreSpace(&p, 100, 20, sizeof *p))
{
  // panic
}
```

It's the most straightforward solution, if not the most elegant.  C just doesn't lend itself to dynamic type information.

**Edit**

Changed the type of `pnt` in response to Steve's comment.

As caf points out, this won't work, even with the "fix" per Steve. R.'s right; don't do this.

Comment: This won't work without the use of pointers to pointers. *p is never assigned the value returned by realloc.

Comment: @Steve Melvin.  Duh.  I knew that.  Really.  I'll edit the example to fix that.  Wow, two downvotes in one day; that's a record for me.

Comment: It's not allowed to modify an object of type `int *` using an lvalue of type `void *` - such code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @caf: Gah!  I think I'm just going to strike the whole thing.